# Reformat Unix timestamp on MongoImport with --columnsHaveTypes?

Tags: mongodb, sqlite, csv, epoch, mongoimport

I'm trying to import data from a large CSV into MongoDB using MongoImport. The date column type is giving me problems.

The CSV has the date in epoch time, but I want it saved into MongoDB was a normal date type.

I'm using [`--columnsHaveTypes`](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongoimport/#std-option-mongoimport.--columnsHaveTypes) with `--fieldFile`, but I can't figure out or find any answers anywhere for how to convert the date format on import.

The documentation makes it seem like I can use the Go Lang format of `columnName.date(1136239445)` (that's the [reference time in the documentation](https://golang.org/src/time/format.go)), but that won't work. And I can't find any help in `date_ms(<arg>)` or `date_oracle(<arg>)`.

As much as possible, this needs to be a hands-off operation because the large DB dump (SQLite3 format) will be automatically converted to CSV and imported to MongoDB without human input.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you change the dump format. By default Sqlite stores date values as ISO string.

Comment: Is the timestamp correct? I would use 1136214245

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, no, I can't change the dump format.

1136239445 is the reference time from the documentation.